# How to connect an internal audio output from the motherboards HD-Audio port with 3-Pin to aux adapter cable

Tags: audio, motherboard

I build a custom amplifier that fits in a PCI slot in my PC. It has an AUX input that has been tested. I was connecting it via an external sound card adapter from USB to AUX. However, I would like to use my motherboards soundcard.

I have a Gigabyte GA-H81M-D2V motherboard which has an HD-Audio connector. I bought a special cable which is a 3-Pin to aux adapter(see below) and used the ports 5-7-9. But no device shows up and I don't understand why. Note: all other ports are not connected since I have all in one plug for my front panel (Also it has power).

[The cable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTPyD.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Okey I found out why. First I needed to install the Realtek HD Audio Manager (it's a driver for my motherboard). Then open it -> click on the folder icon -> mark the box deactivate front panel detection -> ok. Now you can use the Realtek Device

Looks like it does not detect the cable as an audio device without the other pins. Also, I noticed the cable pins are soldered wrong, so I needed to solder a new plug there.

Comment: This the cable name if someone needs it too "Duttek Dupont 3 Pin Motherboard Female Crimp Header Adapter to 3 Pole 3.5mm Male Stereo Audio Converter Cable-80cm"